# Do you have to wash your hands after putting on Tefillin

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing

I heard that you have to wash your hands before Davening if you touch your hair or your upper arm. What if a person is putting on Tefillin. When I put on Tefillin, I almost always touch my upper arm and/or hair. Do I have to wash before Davening?

Comment: the other half is here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70056/759 maybe we should merge those together?

Comment: See here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/70073/9215